# Can Xcode recognize class variables in C++

Tags: c++, xcode

For example, this simple class:

```
class Test
{
 public:
 Test();
 int _public;
};

Test::Test()
{
  this->_public = 0;  // Shows _public in color
  _public = 5;        // Stay White
}
```

This seem to work for Cocoa apps, but not on C++.

Just to be a bit clearer from my original post, this DOES compile and run exactly as expected.

The only impact from Cocoa to C++ is the syntax highlighting. I know that this is only a dev "feature" and shouldn't in any case be seen as a "must have" from the compiler it's just that since it's working for Cocoa why not C++ right ? Give developers a nice feature and they'll want instantly even more :)

Is a fix available ?

Comment: This compiles fine in g++, why not use another variable name other than "public" though?

Comment: Just to be clear: does this not compile or run correctly, or are you complaining about syntax highlighting?

Comment: I don't see any class variables in your snippet, only member variables — so what's the question?

Comment: i apologize for not being clear on that one. 
this compile and runs exactly as expected. I am only complaining in regards of syntax highlighting. 
The question I have is more: "why is the syntax correctly interprated for Cocoa code but not for C++ ?"

Comment: xcode isn't a compiler, it's an editor (or "integrated development environment" if you prefer) with an emphasis on Objective-C.  C++ support naturally lags behind since Apple isn't exactly interested in encouraging development of portable code, they want more apps on Apple platforms and the rest of the world to stagnate.

Comment: Yes Ben, XCode is indeed not a compiler, it does provide it (actually it comes with more than one compiler) but with also many other tools.
Though this is indeed a great tools, I still don't understand why Apple wouldn't provide full compliance between what XCode can do with Obj/C and C++. 
To me this more a very small bug fix that need to occur on XCode and how it recognize class variables.

Comment: I'll probably end up file a request to Apple and keep interested people in touch through this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, in Xcode 3 it doesn't work. Xcode 4 however does fix this, as it uses a much deeper integration of the compiler. It's not out yet (if you have a developer account you can download a preview), but it will probably be released soon, patience ;)

Comment: Indeed, latest version of XCode4 fixed the issue.